# Ways to Code Rules of Inference without Package Mathpartir

Tags: mac, mactex

In mac pages app, it seems like it's not available for us to install packages when inserting an equation, so in the wish to continue using mac pages as my "working background", I would like to ask if there's any way to inserting rules of inference such as modus ponens w/o packages using.

Comment: Sorry, Pages doesn't use LaTeX, but rather MathJax or similar software, which shares (part of the) syntax with LaTeX, but isn't able to do things that its developers don't provide.

Comment: Oh I see... because in the equation box, there is "Type or paste Latex or MathML..", so I think maybe should in latex directory save my own package before I can use it... (I can use mathbb in pages, i.e. \mathbb{A}). I think there's a way to store the packages in mac before using, but unfortunately, I didn't manage to figure out.